# Problems finding Main class in sub-directories w/SBT assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am attempting to use SBT assembly(0.14.0) to create a fat jar of my Scala project.

My project structure is as follows:

```
    >top
       > build.sbt
       > api
          > src
               > main
                     > scala
                             > name 
                                    > Boot.scala
        > other directories
```

I am trying to set Boot as the main method to be run in the jar.

I have tried using:

```
baseDirectory in (Compile,run) := file("api")
scalaSource in run := baseDirectory.value / "api"
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory(_ / "api")
mainClass in assembly  := some("name.Boot")
```

The jar builds successfully but when running it I receive the error:

Error: Could not find or load main class name.Boot

Answer (score 1):

Going by the snippet you posted, you could try changing

```
mainClass in assembly := some("name.Boot")
```

to

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("name.Boot")
```

The reason it does not complain is that lower case `some` refers to [something else](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.TypeFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

The file path of your `mainClass` isn't relevant, only the namespace in Scala/Java. Is your main object

```
package name

object Boot {
  def main ...
}
```

?